# Kernel32 issue with MS Access 2010 on Windows Server 2003 32-bit

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003, kernel32

Hi I have recently installed MS Access 2010 on my Windows Server 2003 32-bit. Since then one of my VBA scripts isn't running properly. MS Access is quitting unexpectedly giving this error with Kernel32 module.
[image]

I have used this line in my VBA code.

```
Private Declare Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
         lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal _
         lpProcessAttributes As Long, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, _
         ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
         ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, _
         lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As _
         PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
```

Previously I use to have MS Access 2003 version and I never had any problem. Is there any compatibility issue with MS Access 2010-Windows Server 2003-Kernel32. Please help. Thanks

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184802

Comment: Can you show your full declaration together with the types that you use as arguments?

Comment: @Mike - I have included the full declaration.

Comment: @GopalSAkshintala and how do you call this function?

Answer (score 1):

While I can't offer any specific guidance regarding the `kernel32` issue you have encountered, I would make the recommendation that you start eliminating 32-bit Windows API calls from your code. Such calls will prevent your code from compiling under 64-bit versions of Access unless you tweak the declarations to make them "pointer safe" (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831%28v=office.14%29.aspx)), and in many of the more common cases where Win32 API calls were used there are more generic methods available now, like the `FileDialog` object for manipulating "File Open" and "File Save" dialogs.

In this case I would investigate the `.Exec` and `.Run` methods of the `WScript.Shell` object. There is a description of those methods (and the differences between them) [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/507798/Differences-between-Run-and-Exec-VBScript).